# How do I write an interface for TypeScript when a field name can have one of several unknown values?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and I have a situation where I am mapping an array of objects where each object can have different fields -- or to be specific, a field in the object is an object that can have different fields.

I'm not sure how to write an interface for this.

For instance, let's say I am trying to map my original data, which is `Array<any>` *to* an array whose array elements will look like this:

```
 [  {
      name:string,
     favorites: {
                 "spaghetti": number,
                 "fusilli": number,
                "linguine": number
                  } ,
    } ,

{
       name:string,
      favorites: {
                 "spaghetti": number,
                 "fusilli": number,
                "farfalle": number
                  } ,


    } ]
```

The issue here is that the 'favorites' object can contain a wide variety of fields (all of them numbers) that have different possible names that I don't know ahead of time.

I thought of something like this

```
interface PastaData {
   [key: string] : number,
}

interface UserData {
    name: string,
    favorites: Array<PastaData>
}

const ParsedUserData: Array<UserData> = originalData.map(data  => ({name:data.name,favorites:data.favorites}));
```

with the original data being of this format (this is truncated, of course):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5bb238cbf839d08d65633450",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "390322bb-3e93-4196-853a-e6e7a6f455bb",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,193.03",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 62,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Holder Joyce",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "RAMEON",
    "email": "holderjoyce@rameon.com",
    "phone": "+1 (942) 548-3425",
    "address": "168 Ovington Court, Eagleville, Oregon, 1098",
    "about": "Voluptate eiusmod exercitation ad aliqua ullamco ex officia. Fugiat deserunt anim commodo anim reprehenderit cillum cupidatat magna anim. Do in sint elit deserunt sint amet veniam culpa et veniam.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-09-21T02:55:55 -02:00",
    "latitude": 53.144539,
    "longitude": 111.973422,
    "favorites": {
      "cavatappi": 3.1604049168546533,
      "fusilli": 47.41214262743145,
      "spaghetti": 36.351431171952584,
      "tagliatelle ": 16.540786406823592,
      "farfalle": 29.91825944401951
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bb238cba65b6203c1060042",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "8f258a51-4b30-45ab-8bd3-100afb9aa191",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,852.51",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Calhoun Mclean",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "GOGOL",
    "email": "calhounmclean@gogol.com",
    "phone": "+1 (840) 550-3492",
    "address": "775 Arion Place, Barstow, South Dakota, 3519",
    "about": "Id cillum nulla laborum anim enim magna ea. Amet irure exercitation culpa deserunt culpa duis enim ullamco do do. Aliqua commodo occaecat cillum culpa est aliquip veniam officia quis cillum nisi.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-12-11T06:06:10 -01:00",
    "latitude": -85.141798,
    "longitude": 100.30676,
    "favorites": {
      "cavatappi": 36.419432034499955,
      "fusilli": 84.64117075525127,
      "spaghetti": 86.77410379301949,
      "tagliatelle ": 77.02196537202377,
      "farfalle": 70.6367456562684
    }
  },]
```

But that doesn't work.  I get the following error

[image]

How do I make an interface for an object whose field names can have a number of different values, that I don't know, but whose types are all `number`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For this to constitute a [mcve] you should provide an example `originalData` variable that shows the problem without being a million lines long.  Right now all we can do is guess based on your description.  I'd say... `PastaData` should be `{[k: string]: number | undefined}`, since when you access a property at a particular key you'll have to check if it's defined or not.  Again, though, that's just a guess, since we can't reproduce your issue as stated.

Comment: @jcalz, I added the data.  That was indeed my original thought, to add `| undefined`, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that according to your data sample, `favorites` property is not an array but an object with `[key: string]: number` typed properties!

```
"favorites": {
  "cavatappi": 3.1604049168546533,
  "fusilli": 47.41214262743145,
  "spaghetti": 36.351431171952584,
  "tagliatelle ": 16.540786406823592,
  "farfalle": 29.91825944401951
}
```

Therefore you should change the type of `UserData.favorites` property to `PastaData` instead of `Array<PastaData>`.

```js
interface PastaData {
  [key: string] : number,
}

interface UserData {
    name: string,
    favorites: PastaData // instead of Array<PastaData>
}

const ParsedUserData: Array<UserData> = originalData.map(data  => ({name:data.name,favorites:data.favorites}));
```

TypeScript example available here (don't mind the Angular code):
  [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-56509473](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-56509473?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you say that `.favorites` is an array of `PastaData`, but you provide a single `PastaData` instead.

Change:

```
.map(data  => ({ name: data.name, favorites: data.favorites }))
```

to:

```
.map(data  => ({ name: data.name, favorites: [ data.favorites ] }))
```

And then you'll be producing `UserData`-shaped values.